# Cloned windows will not boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, clone, bcd

Windows startup repair is not effective
bootrec /scanos finds 1 installation
bootrec /fixmbr returns success status
bootrec /fixboot says access denied
bootrec /rebuildbcd finds 1 installation
If I run bcdboot F:\Windows /S Z: - after looking where the OS partition is mounted and mounting the ESP partition in diskpart - bootrec /scanos and /rebuildbcd no longer find that 1 installation.

My SSD had linux installed, I shrunk and moved it to the end of the SSD, then cloned 6 OEM partitions from another SSD into the start of the installed SSD. All movements were done with Gparted Gui in Gparted live except a microsoft reserved partition cloned with dd into an identical partition on the installed SSD. I set the flags as they were on the source SSD.